# Adding sx prop to custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5, together with Gatsby Image. I'm hoping to keep my styling syntax consistency across the application so I tried to add the `sx` prop to `GatsbyImage`.

This is what I've tried:

```
<Box
  component={GatsbyImage}
  sx={/* my sx styles */}
/>
```

This does what I want. Yet, I noticed the `sx` prop somehow gets passed to the `img`. This ends up getting a `<img sx=[object Object]/>` in my HTML.

Although this doesn't really affect my application in anyways, I'm wondering are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`styled`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api) function to add the `sx` prop to your custom component like this:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const ComponentWithSx = styled(YourCustomComponent)();
```

```
<ComponentWithSx
  sx={{
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: "primary.dark"
  }}
/>
```

When you pass the `GatsbyImage` to the `component` prop of `Box`, `GatsbyImage` is used as the root component inside `Box`, and the `sx` object is passed to the DOM element:

```
function Box(props) {
  const { component, ...other /* other includes sx prop */ } = props;
  return <component {...other} />;
});
```

If you want to use `Box` you need to create a wrapper component to filter the `sx` prop:

```
function MyGatsbyImage({ sx, ...props }) {
  return <GatsbyImage {...props} />;
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying to style a custom component, I did it this way:

Use the materialUI styled function, like so:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Star from '../components/Star'; //my custom component    
[...]
const StarStyled = styled(Star)({ position: 'absolute', right: 5, bottom: 5 });
```

Then, in your render function, call your newly-styled component:

```
<StarStyled />
```

Now, your custom component (in this case, the component "Star") will receive a className prop, so you can use the prop like so:

```
const Star = ({className}) => {
  
  return (
    <span className={className}>
      ...whatever else you want your component to do
    </span>
  );
};

export default Star;
```